# urlSession didSendBodyData reports wrong totalBytesExpectedToSend

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, mac-catalyst, nsurlsessionuploadtask

The `didSendBodyData` method of URLSession delegate with `uploadTask` running is called with a wrong `totalBytesExpectedToSend` value. It seems to be about double of what it should be but not exactly.

The URLSessionTask parameter contains field `task.countOfBytesExpectedToSend` which is also wrong. The `task.progress` also only ever goes up to about 0.5

The `bytesSent` value goes up to the correct amount which is about the size of the file uploaded.

my code:

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {
        NSLog("did send body data %ld %ld %f", totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend, task.progress.fractionCompleted);
        progress.setProgress(Float(totalBytesSent)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend), animated: true)
    }
```

Note: this only happens in the mac catalyst version. The same code running on iOS reports correct values.

Comment: File a bug.  NSURLSession should be identical on macOS, iOS, and Catalyst, with the exception of behavior of requests made while in the background and relaunching of apps for handling background session activity.

Comment: @dgatwood upgrade to monterey solved it so it was probably a big sur issue.